# ListView header with clickable images

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I've created the following header for a ListView in WPF but the MouseUp events from both of the images don't fire and I think it's because the header is handling the mouse. Can I disable the header? Or somehow make the images handle the mouse up?

[image: Sample app]

XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Colmun1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image Source="Edit.png" Width="24" Height="24" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp"/>
                        <Image Source="Cancel.png" Width="24" Height="24" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListViewItem Content="Test"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Test"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Test"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Test"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Test"/>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Most likely the up event is handled before it gets to the Image.  Try MouseDown and see if it fires.  Understand you may now want to handle the MouseDown - this is just for debugging.

Comment: I can handle the MouseDown event. I can use this of course but if possible I prefer MouseUp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Mouse.PreviewMouseUp Attached Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmouseup.aspx)

UPDATE

You're right. It only works if you wrap the `Image` into a `Button`.

```
<Button PreviewMouseUp="Image_MouseUp">
    <Image Source="Edit.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
</Button>
```

Maybe somebody else has a even better solution.

Comment: Changing the image to `<Image Source="Edit.png" Width="24" Height="24" Mouse.PreviewMouseUp="Image_MouseUp"/>` doesn't help...